# android ValueAnimator Performance issues,get lag after some work

Tags: android, performance, memory-leaks, lag, objectanimator

I was developing user "eluleci" (https://gist.github.com/eluleci/6e0d02c766b27f6a5253) code 
    it's rippleTuch for preLilop

ok , it's extend Button class for do it,
    when we have one button in our layout, all things work good and animation work smooth,
    but when we add more than one button , like 5 button, by touch them the animation on the buttons get lag and not smooth!!

I cant understand what's the problem? Memory issues? and how can I fix it?can anyone knew where is the problem?
    thank you for your attention

here is my code:

```
public class MehDiRippleButton extends Button {
@Override
public boolean isInEditMode() {
    return true;
}
Paint paint=new Paint();
private static final int AnimDuration = 9000;
private TouchEffectAnimator touchEffectAnimator;

public MehDiRippleButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public MehDiRippleButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    allocated_TuchEffectAnimator();

    TypedArray typedArray_MehDi_rippleButton_style = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,R.styleable.MehDi_rippleButton_style);
    CharSequence charSequence_buttonColor =typedArray_MehDi_rippleButton_style.getString(R.styleable.MehDi_rippleButton_style_MehDi_buttonColor);
    paint.setColor(Color.parseColor(charSequence_buttonColor.toString()));
    touchEffectAnimator.setStroke(paint);

    CharSequence charSequence_rippleColor =typedArray_MehDi_rippleButton_style.getString(R.styleable.MehDi_rippleButton_style_MehDi_rippleColor);
    if(charSequence_rippleColor!=null) {
          touchEffectAnimator.setEffectColor(Color.parseColor(charSequence_rippleColor.toString()),Color.parseColor(charSequence_buttonColor.toString()));
    }else touchEffectAnimator.setEffectColor(Color.LTGRAY,Color.WHITE);

    typedArray_MehDi_rippleButton_style.recycle();  
    init();
}

private void allocated_TuchEffectAnimator(){
    touchEffectAnimator = new TouchEffectAnimator(this); 
}

private void init() {

    touchEffectAnimator.setHasRippleEffect(true);


    touchEffectAnimator.setAnimDuration(AnimDuration);

    touchEffectAnimator.setClipRadius(0);


    setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {
    touchEffectAnimator.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    touchEffectAnimator.onDraw(canvas);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
}
```

and :
(in this class occurred the problem):

```
public class TouchEffectAnimator {
float u=0;
private static final int fadeout_time_helper=29;
private static final int tuchUp_time_helper=14;


private final int EASE_ANIM_DURATION = 2000;
private final int RIPPLE_ANIM_DURATION = 3000;
private final int MAX_RIPPLE_ALPHA = 255;  

private View mView;
private int mClipRadius;
private boolean hasRippleEffect = false;
private int animDuration = EASE_ANIM_DURATION;

private int requiredRadius;
private float mDownX;
private float mDownY;
private float mRadius;
private int mCircleAlpha = MAX_RIPPLE_ALPHA;
private int mRectAlpha = 0;
private Paint mCirclePaint = new Paint();
private Paint mStrokePaint = new Paint();
private Paint mRectPaint = new Paint();
private Path mCirclePath = new Path();
private Path mRectPath = new Path();
private boolean isTouchReleased = false;
private boolean isAnimatingFadeIn = false;
/**
 *
 *
 * */
private Animation.AnimationListener animationListener = new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
        isAnimatingFadeIn = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        isAnimatingFadeIn = false;
        if (isTouchReleased){
            setStroke(mStrokePaint);
            fadeOutEffect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
    }
};

public TouchEffectAnimator(View mView) {
    this.mView = mView;
}

public void setHasRippleEffect(boolean hasRippleEffect) {
    this.hasRippleEffect = hasRippleEffect;
    if (hasRippleEffect) animDuration = RIPPLE_ANIM_DURATION;
}

public void setAnimDuration(int animDuration) {
    this.animDuration = animDuration;
}

public void setEffectColor(int effectColor,int buttonColor) {
    mCirclePaint.setColor(effectColor);
    mCirclePaint.setAlpha(mCircleAlpha);
    mRectPaint.setColor(effectColor);
    mRectPaint.setAlpha(mRectAlpha);
    mStrokePaint.setColor(buttonColor);
}

public void setClipRadius(int mClipRadius) {
    this.mClipRadius = mClipRadius;
}

public void onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {


    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        isTouchReleased = true;

        Drawable background = mView.getBackground();
        if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
            ((ShapeDrawable)background).getPaint().setStrokeWidth(0);
            Log.e("fdsfsfd","fdsfdsfdsf");
        } else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
            //((GradientDrawable)background).setS
            Log.e("qqq","qqq");
        }



        ValueGeneratorAnim valueGeneratorAnim = new ValueGeneratorAnim(new InterpolatedTimeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeUpdate(float interpolatedTime) {
                if (hasRippleEffect)
                    mRadius = requiredRadius * interpolatedTime +u;
                mRectAlpha = (int) (interpolatedTime * MAX_RIPPLE_ALPHA);
                mView.invalidate();
            }
        });
        valueGeneratorAnim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        valueGeneratorAnim.setDuration(animDuration/tuchUp_time_helper);
        valueGeneratorAnim.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
        mView.startAnimation(valueGeneratorAnim);

        if (!isAnimatingFadeIn) {
            setStroke(mStrokePaint);
            fadeOutEffect();
        }

    } else if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

        // gets the bigger value (width or height) to fit the circle
        requiredRadius = mView.getWidth() >= mView.getHeight() ? mView.getWidth() : mView.getHeight();
        final int requiredRadius2 = mView.getWidth() < mView.getHeight() ? mView.getWidth() : mView.getHeight();

        noStroke(mStrokePaint);

        requiredRadius *= 1.2;
        Log.e("req ", "" + requiredRadius);
        isTouchReleased = false;

        mDownX = event.getX();
        mDownY = mView.getMeasuredHeight()/2;

        Drawable background = mView.getBackground();
        if (background instanceof ShapeDrawable) {
            ((ShapeDrawable)background).getPaint().setStrokeWidth(0);
            Log.e("fdsfsfd","fdsfdsfdsf");
        } else if (background instanceof GradientDrawable) {
            //((GradientDrawable)background).setS
            Log.e("qqq","qqq");
        }

        mCircleAlpha = MAX_RIPPLE_ALPHA;
        mRectAlpha = 0;

        ValueGeneratorAnim valueGeneratorAnim = new ValueGeneratorAnim(new InterpolatedTimeCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeUpdate(float interpolatedTime) {
                Log.e("1 ", "" + 1);
                if (hasRippleEffect)
                    mRadius = requiredRadius * interpolatedTime+(float)(requiredRadius2/1.5);
                u=mRadius;
                Log.e("mRa ", "" + mRadius);
                Log.e("int ", "" + interpolatedTime);
                mRectAlpha = (int) (interpolatedTime * MAX_RIPPLE_ALPHA);
                mView.invalidate();
            }
        });
        Log.e("222 ", "" + 222);
        valueGeneratorAnim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        valueGeneratorAnim.setDuration(animDuration);
        valueGeneratorAnim.setAnimationListener(animationListener);
        mView.startAnimation(valueGeneratorAnim);


    }
}

public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {

    if (hasRippleEffect) {
        mCirclePath.reset();
        mCirclePaint.setAlpha(mCircleAlpha);
        mCirclePath.addRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, mView.getWidth(), mView.getHeight()),
                mClipRadius, mClipRadius, Path.Direction.CW);

        canvas.clipPath(mCirclePath);
        canvas.drawCircle(mDownX, mDownY, mRadius, mCirclePaint);
    }

    mRectPath.reset();

    if (hasRippleEffect && mCircleAlpha != 255) mRectAlpha = mCircleAlpha / 2;
    mRectPaint.setAlpha(mRectAlpha);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(0, 0, mView.getWidth(), mView.getHeight()), mClipRadius,mClipRadius, mRectPaint);
}

private void fadeOutEffect() {
    ValueGeneratorAnim valueGeneratorAnim = new ValueGeneratorAnim(new InterpolatedTimeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTimeUpdate(float interpolatedTime) {
            mCircleAlpha = (int) (MAX_RIPPLE_ALPHA - (MAX_RIPPLE_ALPHA * interpolatedTime));
            mRectAlpha = mCircleAlpha;
            mView.invalidate();
        }
    });
    valueGeneratorAnim.setDuration(animDuration / fadeout_time_helper); /**change anim fade out time*/
    mView.startAnimation(valueGeneratorAnim);
}


class ValueGeneratorAnim extends Animation {

    private InterpolatedTimeCallback interpolatedTimeCallback;

    ValueGeneratorAnim(InterpolatedTimeCallback interpolatedTimeCallback) {
        this.interpolatedTimeCallback = interpolatedTimeCallback;
    }

    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
        this.interpolatedTimeCallback.onTimeUpdate(interpolatedTime);
    }
}



interface InterpolatedTimeCallback {
    public void onTimeUpdate(float interpolatedTime);
}


public void setStroke(Paint mStrokePaint){
    GradientDrawable gradiant_withStroke = new GradientDrawable();
    gradiant_withStroke.setColor(mStrokePaint.getColor());
    gradiant_withStroke.setStroke(8, Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
    mView.setBackgroundDrawable(gradiant_withStroke);
}
public void noStroke(Paint mStrokePaint){
    GradientDrawable gradiant_withStroke = new GradientDrawable();
    gradiant_withStroke.setColor(mStrokePaint.getColor());
    gradiant_withStroke.setStroke(0, Color.parseColor("#00000000"));
    mView.setBackgroundDrawable(gradiant_withStroke);
}
}
```

and activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_vertical">

<com.example.mahdi.myapplication.MehDiRippleButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Ripple Tuch"
    app:MehDi_rippleColor="#cf030a"
    app:MehDi_buttonColor="#ff2c25"
    />
<com.example.mahdi.myapplication.MehDiRippleButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/view34"
    android:text="Produce By"
    app:MehDi_rippleColor="#f7f336"
    app:MehDi_buttonColor="#d3ce00"
    />

<com.example.mahdi.myapplication.MehDiRippleButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="MehDi"
    app:MehDi_rippleColor="#00930e"
    app:MehDi_buttonColor="#00b909"
/>


<com.example.mahdi.myapplication.MehDiRippleButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="NazaRi"
    app:MehDi_rippleColor="#303dd3"
    app:MehDi_buttonColor="#7688e5"
    />

<com.example.mahdi.myapplication.MehDiRippleButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/view23"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="؛)"
    app:MehDi_rippleColor="#cf0584"
    app:MehDi_buttonColor="#ff0fb6"
    />
<com.example.mahdi.myapplication.MehDiRippleButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/viehw23"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text=":D"
    app:MehDi_rippleColor="#a2a3a2"
    app:MehDi_buttonColor="#dadbda"
    />
```

Comment: use `ValueAnimator` / `ObjectAnimator`, not `Animation`

Comment: OK:)but  ValueAnimator / ObjectAnimator are subset of Animation, aren't?

Comment: no, they are different, more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to dig out the `Handler` which executes most of these animation calls, and invoke `handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);` and that will take care of some of the lag.

Because most probably, when you finish and reenter the said activity, it works good and fast as when first ran. This can be caused by having alot of Threads or Handler messages that have ended their lifecycle but haven't been removed due to being dead.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I can't understand what should I do.
I didn't use any Handler in my code!